# Use Android debug keystore after installing distribution version?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I'm developing an Android-app. Debugging works fine, but after installing the distributed version of the app from the Play Store, I can't run it anymore while developing, because it says the signing certificates are different.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the keystores.
Is there any way to use both the distribution and debug keystores at the same time, or should I deinstall the app each time before debugging ?

Comment: What IDE are you using? If you are using Android Studio, you can arrange for the `debug` build type to have a different `applicationId` than does the `release` build type, so they will be considered separate apps by the OS and can be installed side-by-side.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to use both the distribution and debug keystores at
>   the same time, or should I deinstall the app each time before
>   debugging ?

No. It's not possible. Because when you debugging from **IDE** it's used default `debug.keystore` but your device contains built with your own private `keystore`.

### Solution:

You can set your OWN `keystore` as a Default in `Android Studio`.

**OR**

You should uninstall your previous version and install the new one.